# New ubuntu install on HP laptop. External display not working

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

Installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 (Ubuntu server minimal install) on an old HP TouchSmart 15 laptop. Everything seems to be working fine, except for the external monitor. It seems to be detected by ubuntu, but dual screen display doesn't work.

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2732 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.07*+  40.05  
   1280x720      60.07  
   1024x768      60.07  
   960x720       60.07  
   928x696       60.07  
   896x672       60.07  
   1024x576      60.07  
   960x600       60.07  
   960x540       60.07  
   800x600       60.07  
   840x525       60.07  
   864x486       60.07  
   700x525       60.07  
   800x450       60.07  
   640x512       60.07  
   700x450       60.07  
   640x480       60.06  
   720x405       60.06  
   684x384       60.07  
   640x360       60.06  
   512x384       60.07  
   512x288       60.07  
   480x270       60.07  
   400x300       60.06  
   432x243       60.07  
   320x240       60.06  
   360x202       60.06  
   320x180       60.06  
HDMI-1 connected 1366x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)



$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1 1366/344x768/193+0+0  eDP-1
 1: +HDMI-1 1366/344x768/194+1366+0  HDMI-1
```

Please can you suggest how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.